# If $X \hookrightarrow Y$ and $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$ then $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $Y$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X=(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ and $Y=(Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ be Banach spaces such that $X \hookrightarrow Y$, that is, $X$ is continuous embedding in $Y$. In other words, $X \subset Y$ and there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$$\|u\|_Y \leq c\|u\|_X,\; \forall u \in X. \tag{1}$$

**Question.** Given a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$  such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$ then  $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $Y$?

I believe this to be true, since $ x \in X \subset Y $ and by $(1)$ we have
$$\|x_n-x\|_X \rightarrow 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \|x_n-x\|_Y \rightarrow 0. $$

My reasoning is correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. Like you said, you have $\|x_n-x\|_Y\leq c\cdot\|x_n-x\|_X$ for every $n$ (and clearly $\|x_n-x\|_Y\geq 0$), so the fact the right-hand side goes to zero means that the left-hand side must also go to zero.

Comment: And in this case, can I to afirmate that there exists a constant $c_0>0$ such that $||x_n||_Y \leq c_0$?

Comment: Not exactly, you can affirm there is  a constant $c_0>0$ such that $||x_n-x||_Y\leq c_0$.

Comment: For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed? Or  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ big enough?

Comment: For all $n$. (There is $c_0>0$ such that, for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$, we have $||x_n-x||_Y\leq c_0$).